# Why does the request query value appear strange?

Tags: node.js, express, url

I'm making an `API` using `Express`. The request query was sent via `Postman` to test the `GET` request, but the desired result is not available.

For example, `Postman` created a query as below and requested it.

```
Key : userId, Value : 1
Key : routine[], Value : routine-ZMp@%26nSqOTv1Tsf$459Xp8Ku
Key : routine[], Value : routine-mC%26w*CU!tvTA(RE4pE%234J1d@
Key : routine[], Value : routine-Hn%23fmJ0*90AR%H)6ayLUN$TP
Key : routine[], Value : routine-%23fm%23JO
```

The expected log value of the routine array on the actual `API` server is as follows.

```
[routine-ZMp@&nSqOTv1Tsf$459Xp8Ku, routine-mC&w*CU!tvTA(RE4pE#4J1d@, routine-Hn#fmJ0*90AR%H)6ayLUN$TP, routine-#fm#JO]
```

Here's the actual log result.

```
[routine-ZMp@&nSqOTv1Tsf$459Xp8Ku, routine-mC&w*CU!tvTA(RE4pE#4J1d@, routine-Hn%23fmJ0*90AR%H)6ayLUN$TP, routine-#fm#JO]
```

The log is being output without changing the value of the second index from `%23` to `#`. Strangely, the value of the third index is converted normally. I don't understand what the problem is. Why do you get this result?

Answer (score 0):

```js
decodeURIComponent("routine-Hn%23fmJ0*90AR%H)6ayLUN$TP")
```

throws a "URI malformed exception", because the `%` preceding the `H` is not percent-encoded. I assume that this value is therefore left un-decoded. The correctly encoded query value would be

```
Key : routine[], Value : routine-Hn%23fmJ0*90AR%25H)6ayLUN$TP
```